# Liquid Template - Item ID

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

Can someone please assist how can I pull the itemid from the below using a liquid template?:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 3688882438313,
      "line_items": [
        {
          "id": 9698678243497
        },
        {
          "id": 9698678276265
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

I can get the order id from the following template:

{     
   "Order" : [   
      {% for order in content.orders%}      
      {          
         "ID" : "{{ order.id }}",
      },  
      {% endfor %}   
   ]
}
```

But cannot seem to pull the item ID no matter what I try and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I provided a sample of liquid to get itemId for your reference, if you want other json format of itemId as result, please let me know and provide a sample of the format you want.

Comment: Hi, any update about this post ?

Comment: Thank you it is greatly appreciated. Works a treat. Issue I am having now is trying to include a if or filter.

Comment: If your original problem was solved, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks. And for your new question, please provide more details of how do you want to include a "if" or "filter" ? What do you want to implement by include a "if" or "filter" ? Then I will continue to help you solve it.

Comment: Perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, here provide a sample of liquid for your reference:

```
{     
    "Order" : [   
        {% for order in content.orders%}      
            {          
                "ID" : "{{ order.id }}",
                "ItemIds": [
                    {% for item in order.line_items%}
                        {
                            "itemId": "{{item.id}}"
                        },
                    {% endfor %}
                ]
            },  
        {% endfor %}   
    ]
}
```

Run the liquid above, we can get the result:

```
{
  "Order": [
    {
      "ID": "3688882438313",
      "ItemIds": [
        {
          "itemId": "9698678243497"
        },
        {
          "itemId": "9698678276265"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```